# Can all integrals expressed as products be solved using integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

I know that in most cases it would just complicate the process and lead to more steps, but is it possible for every integral expressed as a product to be solved using the integration by parts method?

Comment: $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ famously does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: btw all integrals can be expressed as 'products' - ie. $\int 1\times f(x)\quad dx$

Comment: Generally, any method which claims to solve all integrals is bound to be faulty. Integration is hard. Really really hard.

Answer (score 3):

There are many integrals which cannot be "solved" in terms of elementary functions or by integration by parts even though they can be written as a product. One such well-know example is

$$\int\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx$$